# ASP.NET MVC3 handle Time out in AsyncController

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I handle Timeouts in asp.net mvc3 async controller?.

Comment: Wouldn't the timeout have to be handled by the client?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way of handling timeouts with AsyncController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600530/best-way-of-handling-timeouts-with-asynccontroller)